# stopping when user enters the 'enter' key

Tags: c++, string, vector, segmentation-fault

i've been writing a program that takes input from the user in two different "vectors" and stoping when enter key is hit.The code is given below

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> a,c;
    string b;
    int m=0;//,words = 0;
    do
    {
        cin>>a[m];
        m++;
    }
    while(cin.get()!= '\n');

    int n=0;
    do
    {
        cin>>c[n];
        n++;
    }
    while(cin.get() != '\n');

    int mida=a.size()/2, midc=c.size()/2;
    int count;
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                if(a[i] == c[j])
                count++;
            }

    if(count >= mida  || count >= midc)
        cout<<"similar"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"dissimilar"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is that when i run the code after entering the words i need to put into the vector something like 'mango' 'orange' seperated by spaces, however
as soon as i hit enter  i get a segmentation fault. Could anyone tell  me whats could possibly going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) object, it starts out *empty*, its `size` will be zero and all indexing in it will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior* (and probable crashes).

You can use [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to append elements to the vectors. Like

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
a.push_back(s);
```

---

While the above is the most likely reason for the crash you're having, it's not your only problem. Another is that each string of input might be ended with a newline. If you want to read a full line and then separate it into "words" then I suggest you use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the full line, then use an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to get the separate words from the line.

You can also use [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to easily [append](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) strings from an input stream to a vector.

You could do something like

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream iss(line);

a = std::vector<std::string>(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
                std::string>(std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin>>a[m];`

You are indexing past the end of the vector `a`. Because the vector hasn't been given a size, it has no space for even `a[0]` to be assigned.

A possible soution is to use a temporary variable to get the user input and then `a.push_back[input]`.

Comment: Try ( not ]. Ditto for the end